# Issue in converting text into barcode with a barcode font

Tags: objective-c, fonts

I can not convert a text into a barcode using a custom font.

I follow this tutorial but sadly is not working.  https://www.idautomation.com/font-encoders/ios-xcode/

My code is the following

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    [super viewWillAppear:true];
    [_lblBarCode setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Bar3of9" size:14.0]];
    [_textView setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Bar3of9" size:14.0]];
    _lblBarCode.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"BarcodeFont" size:14.0];
     _textView.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"BarcodeFont" size:14.0];

}
```

I also add the reference from the fonts in Plist.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/rEAk8.jpg

But is not working. My problem is that I could use a library to generate the barcode but I have to use a font. Thank you!!.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that in your *Info.plist* you have not given the real names of your font files. They end in *.ttf*. You need to include that.

Comment: Yeah I did it later on but it did not work. Hours later I tried using a different font and surprisingly all went ok. Apparently some fonts don't work on iOS because I used this fonts on Android and worked perfectly. Thank you for your answer!.